# Ignore Redis Cache key

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I am using redis in node.js application.
On first request i get data from database and save content in **Redis cache**.
Sample keys list

[image: Keys]

I want to ignore cache against key **2000** and get content form database against each request.
I do not want to change code like add ignore in application code. Want to know about server side configuration.
Is it possible?
How can i achieve this?

Comment: Huh? Just change your code to ignore key 2000.

Comment: I do not want to change in node js application code.

Comment: Good luck with that then. :)

Comment: well, redis is open source https://github.com/antirez/redis

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to configure Redis in such a way to give you data without some keys with a certain prefix. This is what you usually do in your application code.

If you insist on not changing your application then your only options would be to replicate the database with every data excluding those keys that match the prefix that you want to reject. But for that you would still need to write a custom application just to handle a replication like that so it would be even more work than to add that logic to your application in the first place. I'm not even talking about keeping those two databases in sync. That would be a challenge to do efficiently.